# Fuelphp SUM in join issue

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum, fuelphp

I'm having a bit of a problem with join `SUM` in fuel php.

When I use it like this

```
$query = DB::select(
            'stream_post.*',
            'SUM(stream_comment.comment_stream_id)'
            )->from('stream_post');
        $query->join('stream_comment', 'LEFT');
        $query->on('stream_post.stream_id', '=', 'stream_comment.comment_stream_id');
        $query->join('users_metadata');
        $query->on('stream_post.user_id', '=', 'users_metadata.user_id');
        $query->limit(10);
        $query->order_by('stream_id', 'DESC');
        $result = $query->execute();
        if(count($result) > 0) {    
            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                $data[] = $row;
            }

            return $data;
        }
```

I get this error

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'SUM(stream_comment.comment_stream_id)' in 'field 
>   What do im doing wrong?

Comment: does column `comment_stream_id` exist ?

Comment: yes it does, i have no problems without the SUM, could this be a bug?

Comment: does `SUM(stream_comment.comment_stream_id) AS SteamSUM` make a difference ?

Comment: tried with a similar logic like this in the past, it still getting the Unknown column error

Comment: That's terribly hard to read.  What's wrong with building the SQL string and executing the query, rather than calling all those functions?  Also, that SUM will never work without a group by.  You can't have an aggregate column and a non-aggregate column in a query without grouping on the non-aggregate column.

Comment: i know i need a group by for it, could you please give me a better example if is not a big request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `expr` function to create an expression in the select statement

```
$result = DB::select(DB::expr(' SUM(stream_comment.comment_stream_id) as count'))->from('stream_post')->execute();
```

Documented here http://docs.fuelphp.com/classes/database/usage.html